# Apache Auth directive cascade to alias directories

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd

I have a reasonably lengthy block of authorization config directives within an Apache `<Directory>` context in a virtual host configuration file.
It has LDAP credentials and a complex filter that will be annoying to reproduce within the vhost configuration file.

Here's a simplified example:

```
ServerName server.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/server.domain.com

<Directory /var/www/server.domain.com/>
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    Options +ExecCGI

    # PASSWORD PROTECT
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap file
    AuthName "INTERNAL"
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://xxx
    AuthLDAPBindDN uid=xxx,cn=xxx
    AuthLDAPBindPassword xxx
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
    AuthUserFile /var/www/server.domain.com/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

Alias /alias1 /var/www/alias1.domain.com
<Directory /var/www/alias1.domain.com>
    # ?
</Directory>

Alias /alias2 /var/www/alias2.domain.com
<Directory /var/www/alias2.domain.com>
    # ?
</Directory>

Alias /alias3 /var/www/alias3.domain.com
<Directory /var/www/alias3.domain.com>
    # ?
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now because most of the `Auth*` directives have to be used within a `Directory` or `.htaccess` context, I am faced with having to repeat the full `AuthType`...`Require valid-user` block for each `Alias` that I add.

The only way I can think of to avoid this is to split the auth section out into a separate file and reference that using `Include`.

As a solution the `Include` would work fine and be easy to maintain.

Is there another way of doing this which gives a cleaner vhost configuration file with less repetition?
Just in case there's a great way of doing things like this in Apache that I haven't picked up in the last 15 years!

EDIT: I should point out that the reason I'm using `Alias` is for easy deployment, I don't want to have to re-create symlinks whenever I re-build that `DocumentRoot` directory. I realise though that using symlinks and `Location` would provide the cascade I would be looking for to avoid the repetition.
The problem I've got I suppose is more to do with the fact that `Alias` requires a matching `Directory` block to be able to restrict access.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mod_authn_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_alias.html) to group and reuse some of the directives, but I don't think it would help much.  You'd still have to repeat a lot of the directives.

In my experience, the `Include` solution works well and is easy to maintain.

Could you apply your authnz directives to all of /var/www?  That would eliminate the need to specify them separately for each subdirectory.  If not, maybe you could move just the sites that need the authnz into a subdirectory, say /var/www/authnz, and apply the settings just once to that directory.